# Hide <td> when i click the print button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Now i have a print button.When i click the Print button hide the existing column content and show another content.Each column  having different contents.

**code**

```
 <button class="btn" id="print"><i class="icon-print"></i>  Print</button>

 <div id="drop1" >
<td><?php echo $detail->remarks;?></td> 
</div>  

  <div id="drop2" >
<td> <a href="#view_popup_descriptive_index" class="btn green" title="Reason" data-toggle="modal" title="Reason">Reason
<input name="app_id" id="AppId" class="AppId" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $detail->remarks;?>"/> 
 </a>  </td>
 </div>
```

**script**

```
  $("#print").on('click', function(){ 

    document.getElementById('drop2').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('drop1').style.display = "block";
    window.print();
})
```

Comment: why have you write `td` inside `div`?

Comment: don't do like this. It will then be an invalide html and i can not see any `table` `tr` here.

Comment: ya.All is there..now i put a small extract

Answer (score 2):

Make use of media="print". This stylesheet is applied when you want to print your page. You can hide your TD's by adding `display:none`.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print">
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_media.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS [@media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) print query.

**[print](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media#Media_types)**

> Intended for paged material and for documents viewed on screen in
>   print preview mode.

```
@media print {
  td {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try adding more text to make this feel more like an answer and not just a comment. Perhaps explaining why this works? :)

Answer (score 0):

Like someone commented, div then td is not very good HTML.

A better approach might be to use nothing but div's and using CSS to create table-like effect like so:

```
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell" id="drop1">
    </div>
    <div class="cell" id="drop2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.table { display: table; }
.row { display: table-row; }
.cell { display: table-cell; }
```

Then your HTML would be acceptable, and you could continue with your hiding/revealing via jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#print").on('click', function () {

            document.getElementById('drop2').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('drop1').style.display = "block";
            window.print();
        })
    });




</script>
</head>
<body>

  <button class="btn" id="print"><i class="icon-print"></i>  Print</button>

 <div id="drop1" >
<td>show</td> 
</div>  

  <div id="drop2" >
<td> <a href="#view_popup_descriptive_index" class="btn green" title="Reason" data-toggle="modal" title="Reason">Reason
<input name="app_id" id="AppId" class="AppId" type="hidden" value="app_id"/> 
 </a> hide </td>
 </div>


</body>
</html>
```